# this keyword inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By doing some experiments with `this` ,I came upon the following:

```
var foo={foo:'bar',hello:'world'};
$.fn.test=function(){return this;}
$(foo).test()===$(foo); //returns false
```

I cannot explain why the last comparison returns **false**. I am sure that `this` when calling function `$(foo).test` is `$(foo)`...
The same thing happens with `$(this).test()===$(this)` which returns also **false**; however `$(this).test()[0]===window` returns **true** as expected.

Any explanation?

Comment: Comparing two objects, even if they have the same content, is never true. Two objects are always different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `$(foo)`, you are executing a *function* that creates a new jQuery object.

If you try your example again but by storing the object in a variable it should work as you expect:

```
var $foo = $(foo);
$foo.test()===$foo; //=> true
```

This is because comparison between objects in JavaScript is done by *identity*, not by their *content*.

If you know a language like C you should understand why, if not I'll try to explain:

```
var x = { a: 1 };
// What happens in memory is that the variable x stores a pointer to a location
//  in memory with the actual content. So in C, if you tried to print x, you
//  would get a long number instead of the actual object, eg: 2435080915
var y = { a: 1 };
// Now we created another object with the same content, but the content is
//  duplicated in memory, it's not at the same place than x, because if it was, 
//  a modification to y would also affect x. So the pointer is
//  another number, eg: 7043815509

// So when we do:
x == y
// what happens is that JavaScript compares the two numbers:
// 2435080915 == 7043815509
// which returns false.
```